# Cannot access postgres PSQL

Tags: postgresql

I have just installed postgres (mac os), however, when I go to access psql it tries to find the database not the user.

I know the username is benbagley (because that's my system name)

I have tried.

```
➜  ~ psql
psql: FATAL:  database "benbagley" does not exist
```

and

```
➜  ~ psql -U benbagley
psql: FATAL:  database "benbagley" does not exist
```

Comment: Apparently there is no database named `benbagley` so you need to specify the one you want to connect to, e.g. to connect to the default database `postgres` use `psql -U benbagley -d postgres`

Answer (score 1):

[As stated in the manual](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/app-psql.html) `psql` assumes that database name is same as the username when the database is not provided explicitly and tries to connect with that database, which does not exist in your case.

Try connecting with default database which is postgres.

```
psql -U username -d postgres
```